# Running a python script with some dependencies in node js

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, child-process

I have a python script to sort pdf/docx file and save them to according folder. This script is working well in standalone mode.

I want to integrate this to my existing nodejs server. I am using child process. But the problem is whenever I am running the file it stops. doesn't give any errors also. If I don't import anything then the file shows output. but when I import dependencies then the file stops running at that line

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  var dataToSend;

  try {
    
      // spawn new child process to call the python script
      const python = spawn("python3", [path.join(__dirname, "./scripts/script.py")]);

      // collect data from script
      python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
          console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
          dataToSend = data.toString();
        });
        // in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
        python.on("close", (code) => {
            console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
            // send data to browser
            res.send(dataToSend);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error.message);
    }
});
```

scripts.py:

```
import os

# Define the input and output directories
input_dir = './sampleResumes'
output_dir = './output'

print("Work started ")
print("input_dir -------- ", os.listdir(input_dir))
```

the output I get:

```
Work started
```

And then it stops. No errors were given. How may I run the full script?

Answer (score 0):

using absolute path solved my issue:

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    var dataToSend;
  
    try {
      
      const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, "./scripts/segment.py");
      const scriptDir = path.dirname(scriptPath);
  
      
      process.chdir(scriptDir);
  
      const python = spawn("python3", [scriptPath]);
  
      python.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("Pipe data from python script ...");
        dataToSend = data.toString();
      });
  
 
      python.on("close", (code) => {
        console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
  
        res.send(dataToSend);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(error.message);
    }
  });
```